# cakephp 3 - emailer - show an error externally

Tags: flash, cakephp, exception, mailer

I'm using the Mailer class in order to send emails after a table record is saved.
This works fine.  I wonder how can I show an error to the final user if an exception is raised.
I found out that the Flash component cannot be used ( apparently the Emailer class does not inhertis from controller ).
The only thing I can think about is to store the error on a table, and then try to show this record.
Is there any way that I can catch externally the exception raised by an Emailer class ?

This is how I susbscribe to the Emailer in the table model :

```
$this->eventManager()->on( $this->getMailer( 'SlsOrders' ) );
```

Using Cakephp 3.

Thanks.
Regards.
Facundo.

Answer (score 1):

First I recommend you to [read the chapter in the php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) about exceptions to get a deeper understanding of them. The short answer is that they'll go up your whole call stack.

I **guess**, because you didn't paste *any* code at all, that your save is triggered from a controller. However some controller must be accessed first (**if** the environment is web, not console) and then some model layer method be called. So wrap whatever code is there in a try / catch block.

The exception will be caught in the controller and then set it to the flash message.

```
try {
    // Whatever might cause an exception goes here
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Do whatever else you want in case of error
    $this->Flash->error($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I will try it. Regards,